# Could not connect to SMTP host: 10.0.1.9, port: 80, response: -1 when sending email through java

Tags: java, email, smtp

i am trying to send email through java code..  but exception raises..  i dont know where i am going wrong..  sending it through my company network..

```
public class SendingMail{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
            final String username = "xyz@company.com";
    final String password = "********";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", "xyz@company.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", "********");
        props.put("mail.smtp.protocol", "smtp");  
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "10.0.1.9");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "80");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "80");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
      });
    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("dpaleti@avineonindia.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse("abc@company.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
            + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");
                        Transport.send(message);
                           System.out.println("Done");
                   } catch  (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
    }
         }
           }
```

Exception Stack Trace is:

```
     javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 10.0.1.9, port: 80,      response: -1
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1270)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at com.ex.mails.SendingMail.main(SendingMail.java:48)
```

i checked in telnet if its connecting to my server..  it connects as well as i can ping to 10.0.1.9

changed the port no to 25. now i get the following error

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 10.0.1.9, port: 25;
 nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1282)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
at com.ex.mails.SendingMail.main(SendingMail.java:48)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:232)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1250)
... 7 more
```

Comment: you have smtp running on port 80 - that is confusing.

Comment: You could try connecting to port 25, the correct port for SMTP.

Comment: yes.. checked in telnet when giving telnet 10.0.1.9 8080 it gives error when using 80 as port it conects!!

Comment: 25 gives error guess my company network doesnt allow it

Comment: just checked with port 25 in cmd with telnet it connects fine.. sorry for that but when i change port no in code it gives error @MikeW

Comment: In case of starttls enabled as false, don't set the mail.smtp.socketFactory.* properties.

Comment: commented mail.smtp.socketFactory properties still the same error @user748316

Comment: thank u so much for your quick reply @MikeW

Comment: Can you check this. Similar issue resolved by settign this property java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true.  [Check this Simualar Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764088/sending-mail-java-net-socketexception-network-is-unreachable-connect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here few points which may helpful for you

1. Check SMTP server running or not
2. If SMTP server running then check which port(may be 25,587,465) listen by SMTP server. `587` for StartTLS `props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");` or use `465` if ssl is enabled

Here is an example which may help you http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/